# how to clear session and cache everytime open microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

How do I clear a session and cache every time open microsoft edge? I am working with selenium tests and everytime I run a test, the old session is used not a new session.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do this. You just can clear a session and cache every you close the browser. Not every time you open your browser.

[This is the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azoYm.png)

Slide **On** in Setting **Always clear this when I close the browser**

Comment: how do I do this automatically?

Comment: If you Slide **On** in Setting **Always clear this when I close the browser** it's will be automatically clear session and cache when you close your browser.